# Disable Visual bell on centos

Tags: bash, centos

i using centos 4 (32 bits) and  bash.

I want to know how disable the visual bell in all the shells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try :

```
set bell-style none
```

To disable it in all the shells, you can add this line to your `~/.inputrc` file (ie the .inputrc file which is at the root of your home dir).

Comment: That command should go in `~/.inputrc`. If you put it in `~/.bashrc` it has to be `bind 'set bell-style none'`.

Comment: you can also uncomment/add the above line in /etc/inputrc like in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36726662/969984