# Disable beep in WSL terminal on Windows 10

Tags: bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How to disable visual and audio bell/beep in WSL on Windows 10?

Comment: Can't you `set bell-style none` in your readline init file? That's 1. the value of the `INPUTRC` environment variable, 2. `~/.inputrc` or 3. `/etc/inputrc`.

Comment: In the meanwhile @BenjaminW. I've _set bell-style none_ in /etc/inputrc but it didn't work

Comment: `/etc/inputrc` is ignored if you have a `~/.inputrc`, do you have one? Or `INPUTRC` pointing elsewhere?

Comment: No I've checked there's no ~/.inputrc. As far as the INPUTRC, I've not found it

Comment: `setterm -blength 0` in .bash_profile

Comment: Yeah @jgr208 , it did the trick ! Thx as well Benjamin for your time

Comment: @shellter I think this question is fine here. Questions don't have to be _about_ programming to qualify for SO as far as I'm aware.

Comment: It is still beeping in vim... Why would anyone like to have a beeping computer? This should be off by default and not on...

Comment: I'm a bit behind on mod powers... how do I flag this for shifting to SuperUser again? It would be really helpful there, and if you came here from an external search engine, it shouldn't matter that it's not on SO.

Comment: Don't forget (like I just did) to source the bashrc file. God bless whoever posted that inputrc one. I have hated that #$%^ing bell for years and it kept taunting me. promises of set bell-style gave me hope only to be pulled away when I would try to git autocomplete a branch or something, leaving me crying in vain for peace. Damn yee bell!! Damn yee!!!!

Comment: Note, this this intrusive turned on by its own settings is per profile, so don't place in global section, can use gui settings, select the profile, then advanced, scroll to button to unchecked audbile bell too, then click save.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/414994).

Comment: @shellter WSL seems to meet "software tools primarily used by programmers"? MS's description specifically indicate that it is meant for developer use `The Windows Subsystem for Linux lets developers run a GNU/Linux environment`

Comment: @GertvandenBerg : Well who can argue with a 990 point self-accepted self-answer? As far as I'm concerned, a `bell` in a terminal is a user issue, but I don't really care. I wish they had never bothered to break up stackexchange. So much time is wasted on "is this the right 'channel' to discuss X" ... Of course, all IMHO. And you're welcome to spend your time gathering the votes to reopen the question (-;!  Good luck to all.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZPvjOsPi1xI&ab_channel=DanSheffner

Answer (score 1045, accepted):

1. To disable the beep in **bash** you need to uncomment (or add if not already there) the line `set bell-style none` in your `/etc/inputrc` file.

   *Note:* Since it is a protected file you need to be a privileged user to edit it (i.e. launch your text editor with something like `sudo <editor> /etc/inputrc`).
2. To disable the beep and the visual bell also in **vim** you need to add the [following](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5310/how-can-i-disable-bells-visualbells-in-vim) to your `~/.vimrc` file:

   ```
   set visualbell
   set t_vb=
   ```
3. To disable the beep also in **less** (i.e. also in man pages and when using "git diff") you need to add `export LESS="$LESS -R -Q"` in your `~/.profile` file.

Comment: For a quick one-time solution sounds can be disabled via Windows Volume Mixer https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/715#issuecomment-238010146

Comment: FYI, I had to restart my console for this to apply, but it did work!

Comment: @TJB I think it should be enough to launch `source path-to-.bash_profile` - or the file you changed - and the configuration will be reloaded, so to save you from restarting the console.
However I'm pleased it worked !

Comment: You can simply type `bash` without restarting for the setting to apply.

Comment: It would be better if you could also add to your answer that you need to **restart console** as mentioned by @TJB or as you said `source path-to-.bash_profile` but many thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: This doesn't work at all.

Comment: I prefer @Nemo's solution which puts the setting in a user-local ~/.inputrc file, and he also fixes the beeps for vim, which is just as annoying and not addressed by this solution.

Finally, note that when ssh-ing into another machine, you need to have the same .inputrc and .vimrc files on the remote machine to disable the beeping from ssh. This is where Nemo's solution really shines, as you usually can't modify the system settings on remote machines.

Comment: In case you need to ssh and don't have sudo on remote machine, add this line to your .bashrc would also do: `bind 'set bell-style none'`. This is actually less intrusive too. Also need to logout to make it work.

Comment: For some reason `source` doesn't work, you need to restart the console

Comment: I had to have the file located at ~/.inputrc and then run `bash` afterward, and it was successful

Comment: Note that to make the changes take affect, you must restart your bash session or reload the file ( `$ bind -f /etc/inputrc` ).

Comment: Sourcing the .bash_profile or in my case .bashrc didn't work. Restarting works though.

Comment: This does nothing.

Comment: This removes _some_ beeps, for example if you open WSL and just hit backspace, it won't beep anymore. However, other beeps **are still audible** (e.g. the one when you hit arrow-down at the end of a vim document). I updated the answer to include how to disable it in vim.

Comment: A more faster way is to directly access inputrc file in the virtual path: `<drive-letter>:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu<version-name>nWindows_<unknown-id>\LocalState\rootfs\etc`

Comment: Why on earth is this not the default? Is there someone who thought, "Man, every time I tab complete what I really need to hear is BEEEP BEEEP BEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEP"

Comment: It looks like this uses the windows speaker driver to deliver the beep.  You can disable that from (administrator) cmd.exe:
`sc stop beep` ;
`sc config beep start= disabled`

Comment: Pleas, add the "restart terminal for changes to apply" in the bullet points since your answer works but only after the modified files are applied to your profile (hence you need to restart the terminal). I am giving you my upvote anyways

Comment: This works great for the local WSL but doesn't work when you ssh into a server (at least not when I ssh into my Raspberry). You have to disable this on each server. But if you are using [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), you can set `"bellStyle": "none"` in your profile defaults:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-1-5-release/#audible-bell-%f0%9f%94%94

Comment: If by any chance you are using "Windows Terminal" and you want to do it easy an fast, you can disable the terminal's bell sound directly it's config file instead of "muting" the sound in the sound mixer, you just add `"bellStyle": "none"` to your settings, and if you want to re enable just delete that line of change `none` to `audible`. No need of restarting the terminal, closing the tab or anything special, works when you save the config file.

Comment: Thanks, it drove me nuts after already a few minutes working in WSL.

Comment: @GrantCurell Because it is so fun to terrorize all collegues in an open office environment. It also promotes increasing your social network at work, because you need to get a new seat every day.

Answer (score 320):

Since the only noise terminals tend to make is the bell and if you want it off everywhere, the very simplest way to do it for bash on Windows:

1. Mash backspace a bunch at the prompt
2. Right click sound icon and choose Open Volume Mixer
3. Lower volume on Console Window Host to zero

Comment: I really like the simplicity

Comment: Given that I ssh into a lot of servers and cannot easily manage local bash settings on all the servers, this solution was the best one for me because it was global.

Comment: a windows solution for a windows-caused problem :D

Comment: `set bell-style none`, `setterm -blength 0` and `set visualbell` didn't work for me but this did, Thank you so much.

Comment: What am I missing? I've tried various configurations, but when I open Volume Mixer all I see is "System Sounds" -- no Console Window Host. I even tried this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/applications-missing-from-volume-mixer/b64bce0f-9fac-456f-a5cd-f77a59cdc6f8

Comment: Did you press backspace for a bit or some other key to make the console window make noise?  Do this before opening the mixer.  Applications won't appear in the mixer until Windows determines they're making noise.  It will then remove them after awhile.

Comment: Cheese-and-rice! this is the only thing which worked for me. How f-ing annoying. Thanks @TedMilker

Comment: We need a special up vote for the funniest working solution. :-)

Comment: I have tried every trick listed - nothing worked. I avoided your solution because as chris says it's funny. :) And as TedMilker says - f-ing annoying. Thank you!!

Comment: This solution didn't work for me until I decided to follow step 1.

Comment: Sorry, but really, the solution is to turn down the volume? That's like someone asking how to make the screen darker and I tell them to turn off their monitor. What did I miss?

Comment: @corwin.amber scroll to the right, esp if you use firefox

Comment: @DanChase This works for everything in a terminal -with one change-, not just shells.  If you use vim(I do) then you need to edit at least two files which is annoying.  Also, more files to edit if you remote into other sites through the terminal.  This kills the Terminal's bell completely in one easy place.

Comment: glad this simple step really worked to get rid of those annoying sound in terminal....

Comment: This solution also work for setting very low volume which is also fine for me. Thanks!

Comment: does anybody know how this solution (muting the terminal in the Volume Mixer) can be configured to be boot resistant?

Comment: One edge case still exists: When the sound comes out of a bluetooth speaker / headphones that is connected with two devices simulatiounsly, the device running the terminal is still priviledged. Therefore, windows seems to send a sound with 0% volume information to the device and the playpack of the second device stops.

Comment: This is a good solution but I found that it did not persist. After some time, the mute disappeared, it's like new instances showed up which required muting again. Also, this needs to be repeated for every new terminal Window.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution IMAO

Answer (score 128):

You need add following lines to bash and vim config,

1) Turn off bell for bash

```
vi ~/.inputrc
set bell-style none
```

2) Turn off bell for vi

```
vi ~/.vimrc
set visualbell
set t_vb=
```

Setting the visual bell turns off the audio bell and clearing the visual bell length deactivates flashing.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is my favorite as it addresses both sources of beeping, the terminal itself and vim, plus avoids the flashing from the visual bell.

I also like that you're creating user profiles instead of editing the system config files in /etc

Comment: Note that this also works nicely to disable beeping from ssh when accessing a remote machine, just create the same files in your home folder on the remote machine and no more beeps.

Comment: Im using git git version 2.31.0. Windows ten. Windows terminal. Setting my inputrc file to "set bell-style none" worked for me.

Comment: This does work in bash, thanks! But if you enter a Python REPL from bash, `print('\a')` will still make a bell sound.

Answer (score 124):

Uncommenting `set bell-style none` in `/etc/inputrc` and creating a `.bash_profile` with `setterm -blength 0` didn't stop vim from beeping.

What worked for me was creating a `.vimrc` file in my home directory with `set visualbell`.

Source: https://linuxconfig.org/turn-off-beep-bell-on-linux-terminal

Comment: Wow, why what when were did someone think beeping was a good default? Thanks! Your answer is needed to turn off the bell sound in vi.

Comment: Does work for local, but no good for ssh to remote servers.

Comment: @Matt - for SSH session you need to tweak the setting in the SSH client you're using. For example, if you're using PuTTY then tweak its settings.

Comment: you need both a ~/.inputrc and a ~/.vimrc to remove the beeps both from bash and from vim, see @Nemo's solution.
Also note that you need these two files on remote machines you're ssh-ing into if you want to avoid the beeping from ssh.

Answer (score 39):

Replace in System Sounds the "Critical Stop" to a wav-file which is silent [1](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/silent-wav-file.500379/).

Just removing the sound completely did not work for me. Apparently some default sound was used in this case.

[image: System sounds configuration]

(Credits for this.lau_ on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/917070/82043) for discovering this).

Comment: If you have a Linux box it's easy to make a 1 second sound of silence. Install sox. Then $ rec silence.wav trim 0 1

Comment: This helped me. When I set 'Critical Stop' to None, it was reset to 'Default Beep', I had to set that too to None. These sounds are annoying especially when we are on headphones. Windows should learn.

Answer (score 37):

its not specific to bash windows 10.
but if you want remove the bell terminal for zsh, just use the right option in zshrc. (for vim, answer already posted)

```
unsetopt beep
```

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html

i have find this option quickly, but would find it even faster if its was on this post ^^

hf

Answer (score 21):

In Windows Terminal Settings, select the profile, then click 'advanced' > 'bell notification'

and turn it off:

[image]

Comment: Editor here. I've removed your original answer (re: lowering the volume) and left your updated answer which is actually very good. Have an upvote!

Comment: This is the best answer if you're using Windows Terminal.

Comment: This answer is the only one that works on both `zsh` and `bash` regardless of using `ssh` or not. I recommend this one as this is not a hack. This is a built-in feature if you are using Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 13):

I found that TedMilker's solution worked, but I would need to readjust the Volume Mixer each time I restarted. To make it permanent, I adjusted volume levels within the Windows App Volume and Device Preferences.

Taken from [this post](https://winaero.com/blog/adjust-app-sound-individually-windows-10/):

Settings / System / Sound / App volume and device preferences

Set Console Window Host to Zero.

(You may need to hit Tab / Backspace in the console window to trigger the bell sound before the Console Window Host slider appears.)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what jgr208 said, you may have a `~/.profile` file already and `~/.bash_profile` may not be present, as was the case with me.

In this case, add `setterm -blength 0` to the `.profile`.

If you create a `.bash_profile`, your `.profile` will be ignored and anything Windows wrote there will not work.

Answer (score 2):

To disable the beeps when ssh-ing in a remote machine, simply create the same `~/.inputrc` and `~/.vimrc` files on the remote machine to stop ssh itself from beeping.

See the answer from @Nemo for the contents of each file.

Comment: pretty sure `.vimrc` has no point here

Answer (score -2):

Find the location of the `.bash_profile` file and enter the following into the file:

`setterm -blength 0`

Which will set the amount of time the beep happens to 0 and thus no beep.

Comment: This didn't work for me - the other answer about the  inputrc file did

Comment: @reach4thelasers well which beep did you want to disable? as you can see below for vim and the like my answer does work.

Comment: It was the beep that happens when you push the delete button and go too far - so try to delete nothing... so annoying!!!

Comment: @reach4thelasers haha i know what you mean, imagine that sound during my computer lab in college with 30 students!

Comment: Putting the expression in the answer in `~/.bashrc` and restarting the console worked for me. NOTE: I use ConEmu64 instead of cmd.

Comment: for me, only the solution To disable beep of the bash you need to uncomment/add set bell-style none in your /etc/inputrc file worked for me.